# How to get the latest Room version?

Tags: android, database, kotlin

Would you know where to get the latest version for Room ?

On [this Android Studio page](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components), it is quoted that the latest Room version is 2.1.0-alpha3 but when I put this version in my build.gradle file, the project cannot compile and the following error is shown :

```
ERROR: Failed to resolve: android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:2.1.0-alpha3
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to check AndroidX when starting a new project in Android Studio, then in the App Module Build.Gradle file the following works perfectly :

```
def room_version = "2.1.0-alpha03"
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version" // use kapt for Kotlin
```

Answer (score 4):

> it is quoted that the latest Room version is 2.1.0-alpha3

It is.

> when I put this version in my build.gradle file, the project cannot compile and the following error is shown

Your version is fine. Your artifact is the problem.

All new libraries are AndroidX. Your choices are:

- Stick with whatever version you are using right now and keep your `android.arch.persistence.room:runtime` artifact and its classes, or
- Migrate to AndroidX, in which case you would use `androidx.room:room-runtime` as the artifact, and need to change your code to reference the `androidx` classes for Room and everything else

Comment: Ok thank you ! I'm going to update the question with the code that seems to resolve this issue, hoping that it will help other people in the same case :)

Answer (score 3):

The thing is, if you'r using [AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/) then the latest is `2.1.0-alpha3`, or, if you are using [Support libraries](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/) then it's `1.1.1` or whatever is latest and that's what mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components). As mentioned by CommonsWare, it's the artifact, and to find out the mappings, see this [mapping documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate#artifact_mappings). And AndroidX is:

> The AndroidX library contains the existing support library and also
>   includes the latest [Jetpack](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/) components.

Example using support libraries:

```
dependencies {
    // Other libraries...
    implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1'
    annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1'
}
```

Comment: Ok, this is not as easy as I thought it would be. Thanks to both of you for pointing me in a hopeful direction :)

Comment: No but I'm going to try with checking the "AndroidX" checkbox in a new project, I think that this will be easier.

Comment: Or just "Migrate to AndroidX" found under Android Studio > Refactor for your old projects. And if possible update AS to 3.3.

Comment: That is what I did, Rajarshi. Thanks to all that replied!